# rest-framework "get() missing 1 required positional argument"

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I want transmit a GET parameters 'pk' to django rest-framework.

Browser

[image]

but in my view.py I was setting my GET method to receive ‘pk’ parameters.

views.py

[image]

It's urls.py code:

[image]

and There is another one question,if I models object use 'objects' method in the pycharm,were throw an exception,such as:

[image]

but my friend was not happen this exception. He use pycharm 2017.4(macOS)

```
cateloydata = category.objects.all()
```

my pycharm version:pycharm 2017.2
python version 3.6
django version 1.11.7

Thank everyone.

and I'm sorry, I need at least 10 reputation to post images. So my question composing is very bad.

感谢！

Comment: Please, don't use images to post your code.

Comment: Thanks your advise,I use StackOverflow just a moment ago.I will pay attention to that

Comment: modify urls.py =>  url(r'^question/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', views.QueryQuestion.as_view()),

Comment: Thanks,you are right! ^ ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding params to your url, you have to add an extra param to your method definition, like this:

```
# urls.py
url(r'^questions/(?P<pk>[\w:|-]+)/$', TheView.as_view(), name='view')
```

In the url above, you are passing a url param (pk) so you have to receive it in the method:

```
# views.py
class TheView(APIView):
   def get(self, request, pk):
     ...
```

But in your case, you want to pass data by query params.

```
# urls.py
url(r'^questions/$', TheView.as_view(), name='view')
```

so you don't have to receive it in the method declaration, use:

`def get(self, request):
     pk = request.GET.get('pk')`

instead.

Comment: It's a good solution，but my code simiar to official document example, so I'm confuse(I reference the official document example:http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/)