# missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I am new in Django and react. I already faced this error at last week and That times its was request URL error. yesterday I changed backend design and now its error happens again.

Here is my url=>

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^allowances_mas/', AllowanceAPIView.as_view()),
    url(r'^allowances_mas/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AllowanceAPIView.as_view()),....
```

here is my put method that inside view,

```
def put(self,request,pk):
        save_allowance = get_object_or_404(Allowance.objects.all(),pk=pk)
        data = request.data.get('allowance')
        serializer = AllowanceSerializer(instance=save_allowance,data=data,partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():           
            allowance_saved=serializer.save()
            return Response({"success":"Allowance '{}' updated successfully".format(allowance_saved.AllowID)})
        else:
            return Response({"fail":"'{}'".format(serializer.errors)})
```

Here is url request from React axios =>

```
  axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/allowances_mas/1/', { allowance },{
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
        .then(res => {
          axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/allowances_mas/')
          .then(res=>{
            const resallowance=res.data.allowance;  

            this.setState({
              allowances:resallowance 
            });
          })      
        })
        .catch(err=>{
          console.log("error",err);
        })
        .finally(fin=>{
          console.log(fin);
        })
```

I can do get and post method but put and delete can't because of this error. I set the pk key and why it's still happening the error? Thanks.

Comment: Try this `axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/allowances_mas/', { allowance }`

Comment: @shafik, Still happening the error. May I know why u suggest like that?

Comment: Do `get` works properly?

Comment: may be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523151/rest-framework-get-missing-1-required-positional-argument/47523274#47523274

Comment: @shafik, Yes, get and post work properly. These two methods don't have pk parameter.

Comment: I assume the error is here `axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/allowances_mas/', { allowance }` but I can't exactly know where. You can check it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error occurs because you're passing pk as param in put method.

```
def put(self,request,pk):
```

Instead, use this:

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

And for fetching pk from passed URL, use this:

```
pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
```

So your code should look like this:

```
def put(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    save_allowance = get_object_or_404(Allowance.objects.all(), pk=pk)
    data = request.data.get('allowance')
    serializer = AllowanceSerializer(instance=save_allowance,data=data,partial=True)

    if serializer.is_valid():           
        allowance_saved=serializer.save()
        return Response({"success":"Allowance '{}' updated successfully".format(allowance_saved.AllowID)})
    else:
        return Response({"fail":"'{}'".format(serializer.errors)})
```

Also, change the order of URL patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^allowances_mas/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AllowanceAPIView.as_view()),
    url(r'^allowances_mas/', AllowanceAPIView.as_view()), 
]
```

Comment: So request url is still the same?

Comment: Yes it will remain the same

Comment: Still getting the error but this times change 404 error

Comment: Because you're using a get_object_or_404, the object does not exist perhaps?

Comment: This happens before get_object_or_404 line. this happen in pk=self.kwargs.get('pk') And Id 1 is exists.

Comment: Can you please tell what you're getting in self.kwargs? Use print(self.kwargs)

Comment: pk is always None

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195840/discussion-between-jze-and-mehak).

Comment: Can you change the urlpattern to this: 

urlpatterns = [ 
url(r'^allowances_mas/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AllowanceAPIView.as_view()), 
url(r'^allowances_mas/', AllowanceAPIView.as_view()), 
]
Such that the pk one is above the other

Comment: Lol, what the hell is an order of URL patterns? Why the URL pattern cause this error?

Comment: Why would you suggest a keyword argument when a position argument is being used in the url?