# TypeError: detail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am new in Django.

Initially I had this function based view -

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def detail(self,request, pk):
"""
Retrieve, update or delete a product instance.
"""
try:
    product = latesttrial.objects.get(pk=pk)
    newproduct = latesttrial.objects.all()
except latesttrial.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

if request.method == 'GET':
    serializer = latestSerializer(product,context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)

elif request.method == 'PUT':
    serializer = latestSerializer(product, data=request.data,context={'request': request})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Then it give this error -

```
TypeError: detail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'
```

For this I did these changes according to this answer - 
[missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845135/missing-1-required-positional-argument-pk)

Then I had this function based view

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def detail(request, *args, **kwargs):
"""
Retrieve, update or delete a product instance.
"""
try:
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    product = latesttrial.objects.get(pk=pk)
    newproduct = latesttrial.objects.all()
except latesttrial.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

if request.method == 'GET':
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    serializer = latestSerializer(product,context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)

elif request.method == 'PUT':
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    serializer = latestSerializer(product, data=request.data,context={'request': request})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Then I had this error -

```
TypeError: detail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

This is my view -

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

from .views import partial, Detailspartial, detail#

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'partial',partial,name="partial"),
        url(r'pardelete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', Detailspartial.as_view(), name="Partial details"),
        url(r'detail',detail,name="newfunction"),
]
```

How should I resolve my problem. Please help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can revert changes to previous version and change this:

```
url(r'detail',detail,name="newfunction"),
```

to this:

```
url(r'detail(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',detail,name="newfunction"),
```